# Ubuntu больше не видит wi-fi

Tags: wifi, роутер, ubuntu

Приветствую.

После последней перезагрузки *роутера Asus RT-N12* моя убунта на ноутбуке *Samsung SF310* перестала видеть точку доступа. С того же ноутбука из Win 7 подключение есть, с любого другого устройства в доме - тоже. Из убунты же видно много других сетей, я могу к ним подключаться (правда толку чуть :). Ни у кого нет идей, с чем это может быть связано? Я не хочу теперь всю жизнь сидеть через кабель!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что вопрос уже явно неактуален

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну предположу, что в NM сохранен не верный пароль, а так на черную магию похоже!

Comment: Черная магия - это не то слово. Перепрошил вчера ночью "прошивкой от Олега" - всё стало ок. А вот вывод из этой ситуации я сделать затрудняюсь :)

Answer (score 0):

была похожая проблема, помогло обновление разных библиотек и дров через sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade . Если не поможет то не знаю)

Comment: Друг мой, я уже ответил комментарием к предыдущему ответу, что у меня уже всё ок. Я даже закрыл вопрос! ;) Проблема была в роутере, похоже, но это ну очень странно. Почему в этом случае только убунта не могла к нему подключиться, для меня остается тайной за семью печатями)